# Record Audio to file and play from it

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a radio app that i play radio and record it for seeking propose.

I have this `ExtAudioFileRef` for the record file:

```
ExtAudioFileRef mRecordFile;
```

This is how i create it:

```
ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(destinationURL, kAudioFileCAFType, &mRecordFormat, NULL, kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                          &mRecordFile);
```

And this is how i write data to it:

```
status = ExtAudioFileWrite(mRecordFile, frames, data);
```

And i want to be able to play the audio from this reference and in the same time be able to write to the file other audio buffers. It's posible?

Answer (score 1):

I have used AVAudio Recorder for recording.I am posting this code

```
-(void)startRecording
{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMax], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                    nil];

    NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    NSString *filename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sound%d.caf",count];
    NSString *soundFilePathString = [tempDir stringByAppendingString:filename];
    NSURL *urlSoundFile=[[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePathString];
    NSLog(@"%@",soundFilePathString);
    soundRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:urlSoundFile settings:recordSettings error: &error];
    [soundRecorder prepareToRecord];
    [soundRecorder setMeteringEnabled:YES];
    [soundRecorder updateMeters];
    [soundRecorder record];
    double power = [soundRecorder peakPowerForChannel:0];
    NSLog(@"%f",power);
    if (power > .01f && soundRecorder.recording==NO)
    {
        [soundRecorder record];
    } else if (power < .01f && soundRecorder.recording==YES)
    {
        [soundRecorder stop];
    }
    if(!soundRecorder.recording)
    {
        [soundRecorder updateMeters];
        double peakPowerForChannel = pow(10, (ALPHA* [soundRecorder peakPowerForChannel:0]));
        lowPassResults = ALPHA * peakPowerForChannel + (1.0 - ALPHA) * lowPassResults;
        NSLog(@"%f",[soundRecorder peakPowerForChannel:0]);
        NSLog(@"%f",peakPowerForChannel);
        if (peakPowerForChannel>.01 && flagForContinuousRecording)
        {
            flagForContinuousRecording=NO;
//            [timerForUserVoiceRecognition invalidate];
            soundRecorder.delegate = self;
            [soundRecorder record];
        }
        if (peakPowerForChannel<.01 && !flagForContinuousRecording)
        {
            [soundRecorder stop];
            [self playRecodedAudio];
        }
    }
}
```

After recording i am playing recorded audio using below written function

```
-(void)playRecodedAudio
{
    NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    NSString *filename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"sound%d.caf",count];
//    NSString *filename=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"mario-theme.mp3"];
    NSString *soundFilePathString = [tempDir stringByAppendingString:filename];
    //[self modifySpeedOf:(CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:soundFilePathString] byFactor:1 andWriteTo:(CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:soundFilePathString]];
    [[CDAudioManager sharedManager].soundEngine unloadBuffer:soundSlot];
    [[CDAudioManager sharedManager].soundEngine loadBuffer:soundSlot filePath:soundFilePathString];
    [[[CDAudioManager sharedManager] soundEngine]  setMasterGain:2.0];
    //[[CDAudioManager sharedManager].soundEngine playSound:soundSlot channelGroupId:0 pitch:1.5f pan:0.0f gain:5.0f loop:NO];
    [[CDAudioManager sharedManager].soundEngine playSound:soundSlot sourceGroupId:0 pitch:1.5f pan:0.0f gain:5.0f loop:NO];
    flagForContinuousRecording=YES;
}
```